# Location of global libraries for Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, python-sip

I'm fighting with installation SIP for Python on Mac OS X. Finally after compilation and installation when I run console form folder of SIP (locally) I can import sipconfig, but when I`m in other folder I cant - there is no module called sipconfig.

My question is - Where is folder to which I have to copy modules if I want to have them available globally (like "import os"), or how I can check it, because location "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/" doesn`t work.

Comment: If /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages doesn't work, then you are probably using a version of Python other than the system Python.

Answer (score 67):

Try checking your python's sys.path list with:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 32):

A simple method I use is to ask a module where it is:

```
import os
print(os.__file__)
```

Answer (score 11):

`/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/` is indeed the right place (assuming it's Mac OS 10.6 "Snow Leopard" - you didn't mention which).

As @diatoid mentioned, check your system path (and make sure you're actually using Python 2.6 by running `python -V`).

Answer (score 11):

For Python 3.5, It's `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: Make sure you aren't using your user Library and use the Macintosh HD Library, this caught me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can designate an additional locations when python starts up by setting the environmental variable PYTHONPATH.

If you add to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zscrc (depending on your default shell) something like:

PYTHONPATH=/Library/MyPyhonPackages:/Another/Location;
export PYTHONPATH

Then those locations will be added to "sys.path" whenever python starts up.

This will give you additional places to store your own packages or modules.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! Your answer is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: The reason I added it here was because this is where I landed when looking for how to add locations to the global list and thought this might be useful to others looking for this. I apologise unreservidly if it was not appropriate to do so.