# changing python path on mac?

Tags: python, macos

I would like to change my `PATH` from Python `2.6.1` to `3.1.2`. I  have both versions installed on my computer, but when I type `python --version` in the terminal I get Python `2.6.1`. So, thats the current version it's "pointing" to. Now if I type `python3.1` it loads the  version I want to use, although the `PATH` is still pointing to `2.6.1`. Downloaded along with the Python 3.1 package comes an `Update Shell Profile.command` - when I run it and then run `nano  ~/.bash_profile` it says:

> Setting PATH for Python 3.1 the orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
> PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:${PATH}"
> export PATH.

Does this mean that I have changed the `PATH`, or does it just giving me instructions how to?

Comment: For posterity, if you need to check what `PATH` your shell is using, you can type `echo $PATH` in the terminal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:${PATH}" 
export PATH
```

This will append the Python directory to the path.

If this is part of `~/.bash_profile`, this will append the Python path on each startup.

Comment: There is no mention of Python for me in `/Library/Frameworks/` now in 2019 having installed python from python.org. It was here for me `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7` thanks to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741579/1762493

Comment: I needed to also add a symlink by running ... sudo ln -s -f /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 3):

try the below lines

```
cd /usr/local/bin
cp python3.7 python
```

Then restart terminal

Answer (score 1):

For those using a .zsh terminal instead of .bash, you might need to update your PATH using the command:

```
nano .zsh
```

Then update your PATH with the export command.

See the link below for more guide:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-add-to-the-shell-path-in-macos-using-terminal/

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fixed mine by removing python2, i don't if it's a good practice