# Python can't find already installed module robobrowser

Tags: python, robobrowser

I am trying to create a very simple Python 3.6 script. Using MacOS.

For this script I had to install robobrowser, which I installed with `easy_install robobrowser`. After that I try to import it with the following statements:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
```

However, terminal prompted me with the following (infamous) error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "signup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robobrowser'
```

I have installed Python 3.6. However, in my */Library/Python* I only have 2 folders: 2.6 and 2.7. In */Library/Python/site-package*s there is a folder named *robobrowser-0.5.3-py2.7.egg*. Might it have something to do with this?

Sorry for asking a most likely easy question. I can however not seem to figure it out.

Thanks for reading this,

Thijmen.

Comment: Try to find folder robobrowser on site-packages folder inside python lib folder

Comment: There is a robobrowser-0.5.3-py2.7.egg in /Library/Python/site-packages. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, this egg is just a metadata about the package. You must see `which` command for your pip, if this on python2 or python3. I think this is on python2. PS: I create a virtualenv and install in my pc, using python3 and works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the modules that have been installed by pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220670/cant-find-the-modules-that-have-been-installed-by-pip)

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are using `easy_install` for Python2. The best solution is to install pip for Python3 and run `pip install robobrowser`

Comment: I have tried that. Unfortunately it does not work. Is it strange that there is no Python 3.6 folder?

Answer (score -1):

This must be because you have multiple versions of Python installed, and when you installed robobrowser, it got installed to a different python version than the one you are trying to use. If you want to use it with Python 3, make your $PATH variable use the Python3's Scripts path instead of the one from Python2. Or a simpler way is to install pip3 on your computer and do `sudo pip3 install robobrowser`

For reference: [changing python path on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696124/changing-python-path-on-mac)

You can run the `which python`, `which python3` and `which easy_install` commands in your terminal to find which versions of python and easy_install are being used by default.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, 'python --version' gives me 2.7.2 as output. However, any clue where is 3.6 installed? I can not find it in /library/python/.

Comment: You can try running `which python3`

Comment: This gives me /usr/local/bin/python3 as output. However this is not a directory I can open with Finder. Sorry for being such a noob. Trying my best :-)

Comment: You can go there by typing `sudo cd /usr/local/bin/python3` in your terminal. My suggestion is install `pip3` on your computer and do `pip3 install robobrowser`

Comment: It says /usr/local/bin/python3 is not a directory.

Comment: However, 'pip3' fixed it! Thank you :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit my answer so that others coming to this question may find it helpful