# How to include or import robrowser module in pycharm

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm Typing

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
```

but the console is showing that module not found in python 3.6.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community, please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46478207/468724 hope this solves your problem. Also read [FAQ] to improve the quality of question.

Comment: Refer this link ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478207/python-cant-find-already-installed-module-robobrowser

Comment: What is the output of `pip list`?