# Can't find the modules that have been installed by pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I use PyCharm, normally I install 3rd party libraries with the **Project Interpreter** in PyCharm. Today I installed **plotly** by running `pip install plotly==2.7` in the terminal. But when I tried to import it, I got an unresolved reference 'plotly' warning in the editor. How can I solve it?
I got this error when I run the code `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'`

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you get the error after running the code, or just as a warning in the editor? I sometimes get this warning in the editor, but then the code runs fine. And how exactly did you try the import? In your script, or manually in pycharm`s python console?

Comment: @Dennis It's a warning in the editor, got this if I run the code `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'`

Comment: O.k. Did you install the module in the right environment? E.g. if using conda, was the active environment in the terminal the same as the one in your pycharm project settings (or run configuration)?

Comment: @Dennis how can I confirm it, I just ran the install command.

Comment: Do you use Conda? Or virtualenv? In your pycharm "run configuration" or "project settings", you can check which python environment is used. Then make sure that the same is active in your terminal (e.g. `conda activate my-env`), and list the packages installed (e.g. `conda list`). That list should contain `plotly`.

Comment: @Dennis I think I'm not using any of them, after installing python-pip I run `pip install plotly==2.7` in the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179628/discussion-between-dennis-and-ives).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out where the problem is.
**pip** installs packages under `python2.7/site-packages`
**pip3** installs packages under `python3.6/site-packages`

So I should use `pip3 install plotly==2.7` since I'm using Python3.6