# -bash: pip: command not found, but with `python3 -m pip --version` shows the latest pip version

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I get `-bash: pip: command not found` when I try to use pip -V or any other command with pip / pip3, I used to easily install something using pip3 install .., now pip doesn't work for some reason, BUT if I will write `python3 -m pip --version` I will get `pip 21.1.3 from /Users/work/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)` , this seems to be the latest version at the moment and I can no longer install using the pip3 install .. command, using `python3 -m pip`, what could be the problem? I want to use pip3 like before

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need update Path in system variables.
Just add "Python_location"\Scripts\  (for example: c:\Python3\Scripts) to **Path**

Comment: I have a MacBook

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696124/changing-python-path-on-mac