# Updating PATH for python with brew

Tags: python, path, homebrew, zsh

I am relatively new to using command line interfaces and trying to change the Path aspect of python. The issue I have is that I seem to have three version of python.

1. python 2.7.16
2. python 3.10
3. python 3.8 (installed with homebrew)

I would like to do 2 things:

1. install python 3.8.9 with homebrew
2. set python path to be 3.8.9

The issues I have run into are 3.8.9 is not accepted for homebrew when I do

```
brew install python@3.8.9
```

And I have tried to follow the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696124/changing-python-path-on-mac) but to no avail.
I am using zsh. I have python stored in `/usr/bin/python` or python3 folders.

Comment: Your default terminal is zsh. Check the zshrc file. What python path does the file contain? You can update python path in this file. The path in the file is the python version you are using. To update python, try "brew install python3@3.8.9". That should work.

Comment: brew install python3@3.8.9 did not work. No available formula with the name.... How do I check the zshrc file?

Comment: Go to cd ~ then type ls -a. Do you see a .zshrc file? If so, open it like this: vim ~/.zshrc. You can use any text editor.

Comment: I keep getting command not found: Is I did `cd ~` then `Is -a`

Comment: Oh. It's lower case L -a. Copy and paste this to terminal: `ls -a`

Comment: smh... Yes that worked. Now it says E325 Attention. Found a swap file. Options are to open read only, edit anyway, recover, delete it, quit, or abort. I feel like whatever I did previously before asking for help is probably not set up correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241008/discussion-between-vrcomp-and-jack-armstrong).

Comment: Okay, ready to chat

Comment: The link you are posting in your question, is a solution for _bash_. How did you adapt it for zsh?

Comment: I probably didn't...