# Python executable: Where are the module files for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

It is the first time I am coding on a mac and I'm having trouble creating an executable. I found an easy solution but it does not compile the module `#include` files. Does anyone know where I can find the file of the `#include modules`?

Comment: Check this link to know about python modules https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp

Comment: @icy121 I think you misread, I'm looking for the file location of the modules not how to import them

Comment: Your question says "what files are the module file?"
Also Python's path can be found by runnning the code given in answers here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741496/location-of-global-libraries-for-python-on-mac